# Building iOS custom universal framework, which includes other frameworks

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I'm trying to build a framework for social media integration (so that developers can just import this framework, make calls to APIs in this framework and have social media actions in their app, instead of having to import and deal with multiple SDKs and their code), following [this wonderfully written tutorial](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) by jverkoey.

Everything seems to be going right except this little thing. I'd like to add SDKs such as Facebook and Google Plus to my framework, so that the developer who uses my framework will not have to import those SDKs again. But currently, I'm unable to do that even when I build the custom framework with those SDKs in the project and set to "Required". Any idea on how I can get this done will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?