# Xcode - How to put a Custom Universal Framework inside another Custom Universal Framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks, ios-universal-framework

I've seen other questions out there such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18179243/1735836) and I have one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25191681/1735836) but sadly no answers.  I've been researching how to do this and have found three options.

1. Embedded Custom Frameworks.
2. Adding Custom Framework projects to the Frameworks project folder and linking.
   [image]
3. Adding all Custom Frameworks into a Workspace.
   [image]

So far, I have not been able to build correctly using methods 2 and 3.  Is there anyone out there who has done this?  What is the best method?

The goal is to provide end users of my Universal Framework a "one Framework" solution.  I do not want them to have to configure multiple Universal Frameworks....just one.

Comment: Here is the answers to create umbrella framework with screenshots that how we can create a framework inside another framework http://stackoverflow.com/a/27638841/1582217

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Umbrella framework in iOS sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk)

Comment: Yes!  When I asked this question I didn't know it was called an "Umbrella" framework.  Both comments above were helpful BEFORE the update to Xcode6 and iOS8.  I haven't been able to successfully create a Framework since the upgrade and haven't had the time to get it working again.  Maybe soon!